# Gulp: multiple source and destination paths without any unity

Tags: gulp

The relationships between source and destination folders for `sass` task shown in the scheme below:

```
Alpha/Bravo/test1.sass 　→　Charlie/Delta/Echo/test1.css
Foxtrot/Golf/Hotel/test2.sass → India/Juliett/test2.css
```

By other words, there is no any logic relationship and unity between source and destination folders. How we can to compile the `test1.sass` and `test2.sass` by one task and output it according the scheme above? Code draft:

```
gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src(['Alpha/Bravo/**/*.sass', 'Foxtrot/Golf/Hotel/**/*.sass'])
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(???))        
});
```

Comment: You would have to test for "Alpha/Bravo" and then rename the path to "Charlie/Delta/Echo"  and same for other files.  If there is no logic behind the switch in directories you would simply have to test for each possibility with something like gulp-rename.

Comment: @Mark, here the renaming will be conditional (depending on specific source folder we need to output the files to the respective destination folder). The `file.dirname` will not provide us by the info about parent folders, isn't it? So we cannot to define the condition this way.

Comment: Yes, file.dirname will get you the parent folders.  That is why I suggested gulp-rename as one way to access each file's path, test your conditions and set the file's parents to the new folders.